# Excel Tables as Labels or Annotations

Tags: qgis

I would like to take excel tables and place them in a label or annotation so that I no longer have to copy and paste them into the figure layout as picture objects. I know this isn't possible in ArcMap but is it possible in QGIS?

Comment: do you mean the print layout?

Comment: In ArcGIS, you can convert a spreadsheet to a Table and display the Table in a layout, or is yours a pie chart?  https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/01/19/using-tables-in-an-arcmap-layout/

Answer (score 2):

You could export your Excel table as HTML and load it into a HTML annotation.